# How to return max(ID) from any of 10 columns based on Import_Timestamp

Tags: sql

I have a table:

```
> DFL_ID (PK number) 
> 
> IMPORT_TIMESTAMP 
> 
> DSS_ID_01 (number) 
> 
> FILENAME_01 (varchar) 
> 
> DSS_ID_02 
> 
> FILENAME_02 (varchar) 
> 
> DSS_ID_03
> 
> FILENAME_03(varchar)
>
> ...
>
> DSS_ID_10 
> 
> FILENAME_10 (varchar)
```

The ID columns of the 10 DSS_ID's columns are keys to records in another table.  The same ID can be in any of the 10 columns in different records but can NOT be repeated in the same record.  (Each DSS_ID is a partition in the DSS table aswell)

e.g

```
DFL_ID, IMPORT_TIMESTAMP,        DSS_ID_01, FILENAME_01, DSS_ID_02, FILENAME_02

1, 07-DEC-15 10.50.56.933317000, 8650,      a.csv,       8652,      b.csv  

2, 26-NOV-15 10.45.38.651502000, 8000,      c.csv,       8650,      d.csv
```

I want to be able to return:

```
DSS_ID, DFL_ID, FILENAME

8000,   2,      c.csv

8650,   1,      a.csv

8652,   1,      b.csv
```

I think I need to use something like 
where MAX(DSS_ID) keep (dense_rank last order by import_timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY DSS_ID)  but I must admit I'm really confused.

Any ideas would be great, thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  The use of `keep` suggests Oracle.

Comment: Redesign your tables. One filename/dss per row.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your data structure so the values are in separate *rows* not *columns*.

It would appear that you want something like this:

```
select dss_id,
       max(dfl_id) keep (dense_rank first order by import_timestamp desc) as dfl_id,
       max(filename) keep (dense_rank first order by import_timestamp desc) as filename
from ((select dss_id_1 as dss_id, dfl_id, file_name_01 as file_name, timestamp
       from t
      ) union all
      (select dss_id_2 as dss_id, dfl_id, file_name_02 as file_name, timestamp
       from t
      ) union all
      . . .
     ) d
group by dss_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon just what i was looking for.